# Difference of unsigned int vectors, interpreted as signed and casted to a float vector not rendering properly

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, runtime-error, eigen

If I take the difference of the two uint vectors in my c++ code, cast to int, cast to float, and pass to GLSL, it renders fine.  But when I try to make GLSL do the difference and cast, it covers the screen in a near uniform shade as if the square I'm trying to draw is really zoomed in.  And yes, I really really do want to do it in GLSL, if only to see how.  Also, my matrices and vectors are in Eigen objects, although I'm not sure if it matters.

[image][image]

Anyway, to make sure it's clear, my projviewMatrix (the same in both cases) works perfectly fine when given what should be an identical float vector to multiply with.  So I'm pretty sure the issue is with the uint vector subtraction in GLSL.  I did the exact same operation (uint vector subtract, cast to int, and cast to float) in c++ as I do in my shader, but one worked and one didn't.

Here's the vertex shader I'm currently trying.  I tried just considering the vectors as signed ints and doing the subtract since the op should be the same... I think.  No change in behavior.

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projviewMatrix;
uniform ivec3 camera;

in ivec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;

out vec3 pass_Color;

void main()
{
 gl_Position = projviewMatrix * vec4(in_Position - camera, 1.0);
 pass_Color = in_Color;
}
```

I've tried passing `in_Position` and `camera` as uvec3s and then doing `ivec4(in_Position - camera, 1)` and other various silly rearranging to no avail.  Also tried renaming `camera` to `in_Camera`.  I'll admit, that was desperate.

My uniform passing stuff.  When I pass in the working float vector, I simply comment out the 2 camera lines.

```
GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "projviewMatrix"); //this is an ortho projection with 1/2 scaling, no rotation or translation
GLint cameraLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "camera");

glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, projview.data());
glUniform3uiv(cameraLoc, 1, camera.pos.data());
```

This is how I bind the VBO to the VAO.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * sizeof(GLint), 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_INT, false, 0, 0);
```

Here is the float vector input GLSL that works.  `in_Position` is the `in_Position` from above minus `camera` and casted to int then float in my c++ code.

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projviewMatrix;

in vec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;

out vec3 pass_Color;

void main()
{
 gl_Position = projviewMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
 pass_Color = in_Color;
}
```

My projviewMatrix only does two things: ortho projection and 1/2 scaling.  No translation or rotation, or whatever else.  The ortho part of it is generated with these parameters, with width/height being the window width/height.

```
proj = orthoProj(-width, width, -height, height, -4, 4);
```

**edit:**
**At Alf's request:**

This happens right after I bind my uniform stuff:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
int* buffer = (int*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

static const int width = 1000;
TestObject& test = game.test;

buffer[0] = test.pos[0] - width;
buffer[1] = test.pos[1] - width;
buffer[2] = 0;
```

And I continually fill out `buffer` manually like so.  `test.pos` is the center of the square, which is equal to `camera.pos` xy coords (1 << 31, 1 << 31) currently.  In the case where I do the subtraction in c++, I have 3 lines like this after each vertex in buffer:

```
buffer[0] -= camera.pos[0];
buffer[1] -= camera.pos[1];
buffer[2] -= camera.pos[2];
```

Either way, I pass in the data as integers.  The above block (happening for each `buffer` vertex) is the only difference between my "subtract in GLSL" and "subtract in c++" stuff, besides the camera uniform binding and the GLSL code difference.

`test.pos` and `camera.pos` are both `Eigen::Vector3ui` objects, so uint vector 3s.

**edit2:**

I think it's also worth noting that I have debug output printing any errors in the shaders, and there are none.  Also, if I change `in_Position` and `camera` to `vec3`, the result is the same blue-green shade as with anything else.

If I create my own ivec3 in the vertex shader and use it in place of `camera`, I can alter the "camera" values and move around what I can now confirm is the super inflated square, roughly spanning from 0 to 1 << 32 in the x and y axes.  No amount of type juggling or intermediate variables in my vertex shader seem to be capable of fixing this.

**edit 3:**

Using `glVertexAttribIPointer()` to put data into `in_Position` has fixed part of the issue, which definitely appears to be OpenGL doing an extra cast to float before my GLSL code executes.  However, the `camera` vector is still bugged up in the same fashion, and I don't know of anything I can do beyond my current use of `glUniform3uiv`.  I tried using `glUniform3ui` and putting in its 3 values, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you show some of the C++ code

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, posted everything relevant (I think).  Thanks in advance for looking at this

Comment: 1. When sending ints try glVertexAttribIPointer() instead of glVertexAttribPointer().

Comment: @OlegTitov Ah, halfway there!  When I create a "fake" camera `ivec3` inside my shader with values hardcoded in there, and glVertexAttribIPointer() to pass in my VBO as you suggested, it works perfectly.  But using my real `uniform ivec3 camera` still produces the incorrect output.  So a similar problem is afflicting my camera vector as well, but I don't see an analogous solution...

Comment: As I can see now you setup unifrm with glUniform3uiv() and your uniform is declared as ivec4. May be this is the source?

Comment: @OlegTitov The camera uniform is declared as ivec3...  It does seem that OpenGL is casting the camera vector to float for some reason, but I'm not sure what else I can do to tell it not to.

Comment: @user173342 Oh, I'm sorry. I meant you are sending uints, not ints

Comment: @OlegTitov Ya, on the assumption that the op is the same so an extraneous cast from uint to int after subtraction is pointless.  When I use my "fake camera" vector that I declare and fill inside my vertex shader, I declare it as `ivec3` and fill it with (1 << 31, 1 << 31, 1) and it still works.

Comment: @user173342 So if you change camera to be uvec and add additional cast from uvec to ivec for camera only in your shader you'll still have wrong result?

Comment: @OlegTitov I tried it before, but it didn't work.  But it works now!  Awesome.  You should answer the question so I can check it.

Comment: OpenGL is so unpredictable in some cases. :) Answering the question...

Comment: @OlegTitov No, it works, you fixed it.  I didn't know about transform feedback, though, and I'll look into it for future use.  I just wanted to give you SO points for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems.

1. Pointers to integer attributes should be set with `glVertexAttribIPointer()` since `glVertexAttribPointer()` causes openGL to perform some additional casts to/from float.
2. `ivec3` uniform was set with `glUniform3uiv()` which also may caused unexpected casts. The right solution is to use unsinged uniform and perform cast inside shader.